# query as string type in controller class

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dynamic-soql

Can any one explain me...what is the meaning of below lines. [I get it from This link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_customize_searchpage_visualforce_02pagination.htm).

`String qryString = '<strong class="ph b">SELECT Id, title, UrlName, LastPublishedDate,LastModifiedById FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE (PublishStatus = \'online\' and Language = \'en_US\')</strong>';`

Comment: It may help if you tell us what you do not understand about them ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a type error. They would certainly somehow highlight the code  but that's gone wrong :)

Generally it is a string with a SOQL query to be used by the [Database Class `query()` method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_query).

It should be like this:

```
String qryString = 'SELECT Id, title, UrlName, LastPublishedDate,LastModifiedById FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE (PublishStatus = \'online\' and Language = \'en_US\')';
```

Answer (score 1):

The link you refer is something more advanced about Knowledge development tutorial (and as @mast0r answered, there is a code formatting error), but the basic meaning of that query regards the "dynamic query" concept.

This approach is useful when using Database.query() method to perform a query. 
It's a useful way when we want to have a dynamic query, instead of a "classic" one.

So, you can build a dynamic string that is the same "list of chars" that composes a query.

For example, you can query an Account in the classic way, by doing:

```
  Account a =  [SELECT ID, Name FROM ACCCOUNT WHERE Name = 'yourName'];
```

You can reach the same result by doing:

```
String myQuery = 'SELECT ID, Name FROM ACCCOUNT WHERE Name = 'yourName';
Account a = Database.query(myQuery);
```